# Spring 3.0 multiple @PathVariable's problem

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, path-variables

In my application I have to compare 3 products for that in my controller I mapped request as

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/products/{proId1}Vs{proId2}Vs{proId3}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView compareThreeProducts(@PathVariable("proId1") int id1, @PathVariable("proId2") int id2, @PathVariable("proId3") int id3)
{
   //someLogic
```

when hit my url(http://something/products/12Vs13Vs14)

I'm getting http 400 error

I also tried for 2 @pathVariable like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/products/{proId1}Vs{proId2}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView compareTwoProducts(@PathVariable("proId1") int id1, @PathVariable("proId2") int id2)
```

this is working fine but why i'm facing problem with 3 variables and also there are no errors in server log then how to find what's the bug.

any solution??

Comment: Please show us header of methods. Also are you sure that one of your products doesn't have `Vs` string in it's name?

Comment: I changed my post as u asked. I'm using Integers not strings

Comment: I can confirm the problem for Spring 4, only using slashes as separators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try lumping everything into one path variable then parsing it manually:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/products/{compareIdString}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView compareThreeProducts(@PathVariable("compareIdString") String compareIdString)
{
    // split compareIdString on "Vs"
    // parse each resulting value to an int
```

This is more of a workaround than a solution, though. You might want to debug in the Spring code as Bozho suggested if you want to try to figure out exactly what's going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

How about explicitly specifying the regex you want each path variable to match, as described [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html)?

`@RequestMapping(value = "/products/{proId1:\d+}Vs{proId2:\d+}Vs{proId3:\d+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)`

Answer (score 0):

- make sure the problem is not in the response - put a breakpoint in the method and see if it is invoked
- check log files for any indications
- try using slashes as separator `/products/{p1}/{p2}/{p3}` or `/products/{p1}/vs/{p2}/vs/{p3}`

Comment: I searched all my log files I didn't find any errors..
The only error i'm getting is http status 400(The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ().)

Comment: then try the other two points. And also - could you check with firebug what does the request look like?

Comment: Sorry to say that as our project requirement I have to use 'Vs' must.. any other solution..

Comment: But try it without Vs, only for the sake of experiment and identifying the issue.

Comment: {p1}/{p2}/{p3} working fine and I tried 'Vs' as separator for two id's it's also  worked fine..

Comment: then fire a bug in the spring issue tracker, and use slashes (you can have `12/vs/23/vs/34` for example.

Comment: 12/vs/23/vs/34 for such type of mapping also working fine but I can't understand why it's not working for 'Vs'

Comment: @Raju it can be a bug or Spring can't really chose according to mapping which method to use. When you comment out `compareTwoProducts` method and try `http://something/products/12Vs13Vs14` url again it will work.